# Inyectar un service o factory en un controller en angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

estoy adentrándome en el mundo de angular, y tratando de inyectar un service o factory en un controller, pero me salen errores.

Hago un llamado ***$http.post*** usando un controller

```
var app;     

app = angular.module('AppUPC',[]);

app.controller('formulario', ['$scope', '$http', '$httpParamSerializer', 
    function ($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializer){

    $scope.login = function(){

        var datos;

        datos = {

            Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
            Password: $scope.passwordtxt

        };

        console.log(datos);          

        var url, method;

        url = 'http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login';
        method = 'POST';

        $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

        }).then(function success(response) {

            $scope.persons = response.data;
            console.log($scope.persons);

        }, function error(response) {

            $scope.status = response.status;
            console.log($scope.status);

        });

     }; 

 }]);
```

Luego dividí responsabilidades de esta forma usando un service

**controller**

```
var app;     

    app = angular.module('AppUPC',[]);

    app.controller('formulario', ['$scope', 'ObtenerDatos', function ($scope, ObtenerDatos){

        $scope.login = function(){

            var datos, usuario;

            datos = {

                Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
                Password: $scope.passwordtxt

            };

            usuario = ObtenerDatos;

            console.log(usuario);     

       };         

    }]);
```

**service**

```
app.service('ObtenerDatos',['$scope', '$http', '$httpParamSerializer', function ($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializer){

        $scope.peticion = function (datos){

            var url, method;

            url = 'http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login';
            method = 'POST';

            $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

            }).then(function success(response) {

                return response.data;

            }, function error(response) {

                return response.status;

            });

        };

}]);
```

**Error**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- ObtenerDatos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que noto es que ademas que inyectar el scope al servicio lo cual seria incorrecto, no defines bien como devuelve los datos el servicio.

Analiza como cambie la implementacion del servicio

```
app.service('ObtenerDatos',['$http', '$httpParamSerializer', function ($http, $httpParamSerializer){

        function Autenticacion(datos){

            var url = 'http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login';

            return $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

            });

        };

        return {
            Autenticacion: Autenticacion
        };

}]);
```

Es importante como se define el return del final del servicio indicando la funcionalidad que expone
Tambien veras como se devuelve un `promise` del `http` para usarla desde el controller

```
var app = angular.module('AppUPC',[]);

app.controller('formulario', ['$scope', 'ObtenerDatos', function ($scope, ObtenerDatos){

    $scope.login = function(){

        var datos = {
            Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
            Password: $scope.passwordtxt
        };

        var usuario = ObtenerDatos.Autenticacion(datos)
                                .then(function(result){
                                    console.log(result);
                                }, function(err){
                                    console.log(err);
                                }});



   };         

}]);
```

En el controller es que defines las funciones del `then` obteniendo la respuesta de la invocacion al servicio

Comment: voy a probar, luego te cuento

Answer (score 1):

No puedes inyectar el scope en un servicio. Un servicio se inicializa una vez al entrar en la página, y en ese momento no existe el scope que quieres inyectar. Podrías inyectar `$rootScope`, pero no ayudaría en tu caso. Cambia tu servicio a:

```
app.service('ObtenerDatos',['$http', '$httpParamSerializer', function ($http, $httpParamSerializer){

            return function (datos){

                var url, method;

                url = 'http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login';
                method = 'POST';

                return $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                }).then(function success(response) {

                    return response.data;

                }, function error(response) {

                    return response.status;

                });

            };

    }]);
```

Y el código con el que llamas al servicio cámbialo a:

```
ObtenerDatos(datos).then(function (resultado) {
    console.log(resultado);
});
```

También te recomendaría que el nombre del servicio empezara con minúscula (es la convención habitual en angular), y probablemente necesites repasar el uso de promesas por lo que he visto que has hecho en el código (el motivo por el que he usado `.then` cuando he llamado al servicio).

Comment: Gracias @Pablo, voy a probar, aunque un poco confuso con lo de los service and factory en angular, pero poco a poco tratando de aprender.

Comment: Lo probe me aparece esto

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Se ma había pasado poner un `return` antes de `$http.post`. No he tenido tiempo de hacer una prueba, pero debería funcionar ahora. Cuando pueda más tarde lo probaré.