# Problemas al intentar Enviar Una peticion a mi servidor web, desde una app creada con Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic, ng-cordova

Tengo una problema con una `app híbrida`, tengo dos campos input donde pongo usuario y contraseña y eso lo envió a una `URL` en la que esta el script `PHP` alojado(servidor web que es gratuito) y esa peticion es bloqueada.

Por lo que he leído tiene que ver con la seguridad de navegador(`Cors`) ¿Que se puede hacer en este caso? Lo he intentado de forma local, construyendo el `apk` para `android` y nada, he agregando uno complemento de `proxyalgo` y nada, alguna ayuda por favor.

este es parte de codigo con el que trato de hacer mis peticiones

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$http) {

$scope.logear = function($scope){



$scope.mensaje = $rootScope.mensaje;
//alert($rootScope.mensaje);
var url = "http://185.27.134.110/carpeta/php/login.php";

var emaillog = $scope.emailLog;
var passlog = $scope.passlog;

$http.post(url,{'emaillog':emaillog,'passlog':passlog,'accion':'logear'})
        .success(function(data,status,headers,cofing){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(cofing);

            // SI EL ESTADO ES TRUE SE REDIRECIONA AL LA PANTALLA PRICIPAL DE INICIO SESION
            if(data.estado== true){

                        //SE REDIRECIONA AL ACCESO PARA PODER EFEFTUAR LLAMADAS
                        window.location="http://185.27.134.110/carpeta/#/acceso";

                        //ASIGNAMOS VALORES A VARIABLES GLOBALES PARA UTILIZARLA EN LA SIGUEINTE VISTA
                        $rootScope.mensajeinicio = data.contenido;
                        $rootScope.nombreUser = data.contenido;

            }else{

                    window.location="http://185.27.134.110/carpeta/#/login";
            }

            //alert(data.existe);


        });
}
})
```

y codigo `PHP`

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

include_once 'class.Conexion.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$email = ($data->email);
$accion = ($data->accion);


$salidaJson = "";
$contenido = array();
//$contenidoDos = array();
$estado = false;
$existe = "false";

if($accion == 'validarDatos'){

    $pass = ($data->pass);
    $nombre = ($data->nombre);


    $db = new conexion(); 

    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM registro WHERE email ='".$email."' ");

        if($db->rows($sql)> 0){
            //SI EXISTE EL EMAIL SE DEBE CARGAR ALA PANTALLA DE INICIO DE SESION
            //DE LO CONTRARIO SE REGISTRARA
            while($rew = $db->recorrer($sql)){

                $contenido = array(
                    'nombre' => $rew['nombre_completo'],
                    'email' => $rew['email'],
                    'respuesta' => 'Email Registrado - Inicie Sesion'
                );

            }
            $estado  = true;
            $existe = true;
        }else{

            $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO registro(nombre_completo,email,pass)VALUES('".$nombre."','".$email."','".$pass."')");
                if(!mysql_error()){

                    $contenido = array("respuesta" => 'REGISTRO REALIZADO CON EXITO');
                    $estado = true;
                    $existe = true;
                }else{

                    $contenido = array(
                    "respuesta" => 'ERROR AL INTENTENTAR REGISTRARSE, PORFAVOR INTENTELO NUEVAMENTE!!');
                    $estado = false;
                    $existe = false;


                }

            //$estado = false;
        }
}elseif($accion == 'getDatos'){


    $db = new conexion(); 

    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM registro WHERE email ='".$email."' ");

    if($db->rows($sql)> 0){
        //SI EXISTE EL EMAIL SE DEBE CARGAR ALA PANTALLA DE INICIO DE SESION
        //DE LO CONTRARIO SE REGISTRARA
        while($rew = $db->recorrer($sql)){

            $contenido = array(
                'nombre' => $rew['nombre_completo'],
                'email' => $rew['email']
            );

        }
        $estado  = true;
    }
}elseif($accion == 'getLineas'){

    $db = new conexion(); 

    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM lineas");

    if($db->rows($sql)> 0){
        //SI EXISTE EL EMAIL SE DEBE CARGAR ALA PANTALLA DE INICIO DE SESION
        //DE LO CONTRARIO SE REGISTRARA
        while($rew = $db->recorrer($sql)){

            $contenido = array(
                'nombreLinea' => $rew['nombre_linea'],
                'numeroLinea' => $rew['numero_linea']
            );

        }
        $estado  = true;
    }else{
        $estado = false;
    }

}




$salidaJson = array("contenido" => $contenido,
                   "estado" => $estado,
                   "existe" => $existe);

//header('Context-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($salidaJson); 

// mysqli_close($sql);   
?>
```

Error:

> CORS Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en 185.27.134.110/carpeta/php/consultas.php. (Razón: Cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no presente)

Comment: Hola @Dagg, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/)!!! ¿Podría pedirte que muestres la parte del código con la solicitud al servidor y el error literal que te está dando? Para ello, podrás [edit] la pregunta y usar el botón `{ }` para darle formato al código.

Comment: puse un trozo de codigo

Answer (score 1):

En tu Script `PHP` agregale estos headers:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
?>
```

En caso no te funcione, en el archivo `.htaccess` del folder donde se encuentra tu script:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45678/discussion-on-answer-by-fredyfx-problemas-al-intentar-enviar-una-peticion-a-mi-s).

Comment: gracias brother @MiquelColl  pero tenemos un pequeño problema... hasta donde tengo entendido el usuario Dagg no puede entrar a la sala de chat porque le hace falta puntaje.

Comment: como forma de prueba, ingrese datos a una base de datos y los intente recuperar, con codigo algo parecido al que puse mas arriba, pero aun no me funciona, :/ agregue las cabeceras todo lo que aprendi aqui, pero nada, podra ser que como el servidor web es free, me tenga bloqueda la opcion de acceder desde fuera a datos alojas en este??

Answer (score 1):

Disculpa, no pones tu error, entonces es difícil saber si es del lado del cliente o del servidor, de igual forma te dejo esto por aquí, podría ser que la forma que estés enviando los datos no sea la correcta, yo aplique esto, cuando realice una pregunta:

la variable datos, es un objeto que capturo de un formulario para enviar al servidor. la función que allí puse, esta en un **factory**

```
 function Autenticacion(datos) {

    var url = 'ruta/del/servidor';

    return $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });

};
```

Aquí te dejo la pregunta donde en una me explican que estaba haciendo mal cuando enviaba el objeto al servidor [envío de datos e inyección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4581/inyectar-un-service-o-factory-en-un-controller-en-angular-js)

Comment: encontré su error entre los comentarios, editaré su pregunta. Saludos amigo

Comment: como?? lo encontraste???

Comment: como veo lo que editaste'?

Comment: @Dagg pues deberías saber como habías planteado la preguntado y que cambios notas, creo yo